# s.bind nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to learn Socket for Python 3.6. My first project is a messaging program. so far all I got up to was this,

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print (s)

host = socket.gethostname()
print (host)

port = 8140
print (port)

s.bind((host, port))
```

Once I run it, I get this,

```
<socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>
R1shinerg
8140
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/g.shiner21/Desktop/Python/P2PFile/P2PFile2.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.bind((host, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>>>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure you have host file entry for the hostname. try using 'localhost'

Comment: What does `socket.gethostbyname('R1shinerg'`)` return? Its typical to bind to `0.0.0.0` (all local NICs) or `127.0.0.1` (local loopback), or even a list of IP addresses. Using the name can work for getting the public IP address, but frequently not. For instance, on my machine, my hostname returns `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: please cover your print statement with closing parenthesis like `print(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine on my machine. I believe the case here is of DNS entry in your hosts file. For windows system it is located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  and for linux system it is in /etc/hosts .

Add an entry there as below

```
127.0.0.1 R1shinerg
```

Comment: So I'm running it on Mac so anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: You can follow this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253817/cannot-ping-my-local-machine  this will enable you to add link between hostname and IP in 'hosts' file

Answer (score 0):

try Below:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname("")
```

OR

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname("localhost")
```

`socket.gaierror` -A subclass of OSError, this exception is raised for address-related errors by getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo(). The accompanying value is a pair (error, string) representing an error returned by a library call. string

This may be because the host name can't be resolved to IP address. Check DNS (domain name server) settings and point it to (correct) server.